# Pylons + mod_wsgi -> ImportError: No module named paste.deploy

Tags: pylons, mod-wsgi

I'm following the example here: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithPylons

however, it doesn't work - I get "ImportError: No module named paste.deploy" in the apache error log. Googling in this case helps not - I see some stuff about permissions, but all my permissions are fine. Where does paste.deploy really come from? It comes from PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.6.egg in site-packages, installed in my pylonsdevenv directory, right? Well, then how is apache supposed to know about that directory? Does the actual pylons project have to be in the pylonsdevenv directory?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added:

```
import site
site.addsitedir('/<yadayada>/pylonsdevenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
```

to the top of my wsgi file, and then set debug = False in my development.ini file (and later, deployment.ini file, I presume), that seemed to work...

Answer (score 1):

If you can import (from paste.deploy import loadapp) manually it has to be a problem with sys.path. Also make sure that apache uses proper python interpreter. I have something like this in my "passanger_wsgi.py" on Dreamhost:

```
INTERP = "/home/myuser/bin/python"
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
sys.path.append('/home/myuser/blog')
```

You can try put some debug and check which paths are inside "sys.path".

Hope this helps.